# How to display both regular and sale price on catalog in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to display regular and sale price on this theme: [Yourstore](http://wp-yourstore.theme-smartdata.com/layout-3/)

When I go to the product's page, I can see both prices, but when I go to the shop or catalog price, it's only showing the sale price (or regular one if the product insn't in sale). I'd like that to display something like:

> $1̶8̶9̶,̶9̶0̶  $109,90

I tried to follow this tutorial: [How to Show Both Regular and Sale Price](http://minapansuriya.com/woocommerce-how-to-show-both-regular-and-sale-price-both-on-single-product-and-shop-pages/) but it didn't work, my shop page stopped loading.

In yourstore/woocommerce/loop/price.php, I have this:

```
<div class="product__inside__price price-box">
    <?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>
        <span class="price"><?php echo wp_kses_post($price_html); ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

I tried to use `$product->get_sale_price()` and it still doesn't work. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The issue wasn't in the php files, it was actually in the theme css, because the `del` tag of my html was set to `display: none`

Before:

```
.products .product .price-box .price del {
    display: none;
}
```

After:

```
.products .product .price-box .price del {
    display: inline;
}
```